# How to convert pipeline to CSV format and specify UTF-8 encoding

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-ise

In a Windows PowerShell script, I want to execute code which converts a pipeline to CSV format, and encoding should be in UTF-8. How can I do this?

Comment: Please accept the answer as this helps people out there to quickly find out what a working solution is. The first answer solved the same problem for me.

Answer (score 32):

Add this to the end of your pipeline:

```
| Export-Csv -Encoding UTF8
```

It's that simple.

The **-Encoding** parameter is available for any cmdlet that outputs to a file--**Out-File**, **Set-Content**, **Add-Content**, **Export-Clixml**, probably some others I'm not thinking of. One gotcha to watch out for is that for UTF16, you need to specify `Unicode` instead of `UTF16` (I think the latter makes more sense, and should at least be available as a synonym, but apparently Microsoft doesn't). The full list of options is:

```
Unicode,UTF7,UTF8,ASCII,UTF32,BigEndianUnicode,Default,OEM
```

A couple of notes:

- `ASCII` technically doesn't give you ASCII encoding, it gives you Windows codepage 1252 (which is based on extended ASCII and often informally referred to as ASCII).
- `Default` gives you whichever of the other options is the system default. You can find out what the default is with `[System.Text.Encoding]::Default`.

Comment: I have to use `| Export-Csv -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation -Path out.csv` ([about -notype](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47102147/1026))

Answer (score 0):

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance localhost -Database "$database" -Query "$qry"  -username "$username" -password "$password" | convertto-CSV -notype | out-file -encoding UTF8 -filepath $filename
```

This works in Powershell 2, and in situations where convertto-CSV doesn't permit the -encoding parameter (whereas outfile does)

Comment: i'm unclear why you would need to use `converto-csv -notype | out-file encoding UTF-8 -filepath $path` instead of `export-csv -encoding UTF-8 -path $path`.  Can you explain the difference and why you'd use the former over the latter?