# I use -NoTypeInformation so why do I get header back when using Out-File?

Tags: powershell

I filtered by date this file data1.csv

```
2017.11.1,09:55,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1 
2017.11.2,09:55,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8,2
```

I don't get a header with `-NoTypeInformation`:

```
$CutOff = (Get-Date).AddDays(-2)
$filePath = "data1.csv"
$Data = Import-Csv $filePath -Header Date,Time,A,B,C,D,E

$Data2 = $Data | Where-Object {$_.Date -as [datetime] -gt $Cutoff} | convertto-csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter "," | % {$_ -replace '"',''}
```

But when rewriting with `Out-File`

```
$Data2 | Out-File "data2.csv" -Encoding utf8 -Force
```

I get header back as data2.csv contains:

```
Date,Time,A,B,C,D,E
2017.11.2,09:55,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8,2
```

Why do I have Date,Time,A,B,C,D,E ?

Comment: `-NoTypeInformation` is not about the header but the data type of the rows in the file.

Comment: 1. The usual means for outputting a CSV file is `Export-Csv` rather than `Out-File`. 2. PowerShell will always include the header line. (`-NoTypeInformation` does not omit the header as Matt pointed out.) What's the problem with it being there?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart can't use Export-Csv put double quotes I do want same format as input file

Comment: @Bill_Stewart  $Data2 in console doesn't show header

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`-NoTypeInformation` is not about the header but the data type of the rows in the file. Remove it to see what shows up. [From Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv?view=powershell-5.1)

> Omits the **type information header** from the output. By default, the string in the output contains #TYPE followed by the fully-qualified name of the object type.

<sup>Emphasis mine.</sup>

CSVs need headers. That is why it is making one. If you don't want to see the header in the output use `Select-Object -Skip 1` to remove it.

```
$Data | 
    Where-Object {$_.Date -as [datetime] -gt $Cutoff} | 
    ConvertTo-CSV -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter "," |
    Select-Object -Skip 1 |
    % {$_ -replace '"'}
```

I would not pipe `Out-File` to itself. You could pipe to `Set-Content` here just as well.

---

I am guessing this whole process is to keep the source file in the same state just with some lines filtered out based on date. You could skip most of this just by parsing the date out in each line.

```
$threshold = (Get-Date).AddDays(-2)
$filePath = "c:\temp\bagel.txt"
(Get-Content $filePath) | Where-Object{
    $date,$null=$_.Split(",",2)
    [datetime]$date -gt $threshold
} | Set-Content $filePath
```

Now you don't have to worry about PowerShell CSV object structure or output since we act on the raw data of the file itself.

That will take each line of the input file and filter it out if the parsed date does not match the threshold. Change encoding on the input output cmdlets as you see necessary. What `$date,$null=$_.Split(",",2)` is doing is splitting the line 
on the comma into 2 parts. First of which becomes `$date` and since this is just a filtering condition we dump the rest of the line into $null.

Answer (score 2):

Properly-formed CSV files *must* have column headers. Your use of `-NoTypeInformation` in generating the CSV does not affect column headers; instead, it affects whether the PowerShell object type information is included. If you `Export-CSV` without `-NoTypeInformation`, the first line of your CSV file will have a line that looks like `#TYPE System.PSCustomObject`, which you *don't* want if you're going to open the CSV in a spreadsheet program.

If you subsequently `Import-CSV`, the headers (Date, Time, A, B, C) are used to create the fields of a PSObject, so that you can refer to them using the standard dot notation (e.g., `$CSV[$line].Date`).

The ability to specify `-Header` on `Import-CSV` is essentially a "hack" to allow the cmdlet to handle files that are comma-separated, but which did not include column headers.

Comment: I don't want "properly" formatted csv I want same format I received as input which is exported by an other software, this is part of requirements not to change the format.

Comment: I think we understand that now @user310291 but sometimes motivation is useful in the question